# Loading image from resource to image control

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I've got a folder structure with some images in that I'm trying to load and change in the background of my code using c# (not xaml).

I'm having no luck with this and am either getting exceptions thrown or the preloaded image is going invisible when it should change. I have tried code samples from various questions on here but I'm still having no luck.

Folder structure -> `Resources/Images/Themes/{mytheme}.png`
Build Action - > Resource
(All have been added as a resource to resources.resx too)

The code I currently have is..

```
var themeImage = new BitmapImage();
var filename = string.Format("{0}{1}.png", cmbBaseThemes.SelectedValue.ToString(), cmbAccentColors.SelectedValue.ToString());
themeImage.BeginInit();
themeImage.UriSource = new Uri(@"/ZApp;component/Resources/Images/Themes/" + filename, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
themeImage.EndInit();
imgThemeStyle.Source = themeImage;
```

But this code always gives me the exception "Cannot locate resource 'resources/images/themes/lightindigo.png'."

Comment: What does *All have been added as a resource to resources.resx too* means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In code behind you'll have to use a fully qualified [Resource File Pack Uri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly)

```
themeImage.UriSource = new Uri(
    "pack://application:,,,/ZApp;component/Resources/Images/Themes/" + filename);
```

---

You may also avoid the `BeginInit`/`EndInit` calls by using the `BitmapImage` constructor that takes an `Uri` argument:

```
imgThemeStyle.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(
    "pack://application:,,,/ZApp;component/Resources/Images/Themes/" + filename));
```

Comment: No joy - "Invalid URI: The Authority/Host could not be parsed."

Comment: Edited the answer. It was missing the double slash.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing some parameters on the creation.

Try this way:

```
img = new BitmapImage();
img.BeginInit();
img.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
img.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
img.UriSource = new Uri(@"/ZApp;component/Resources/Images/Themes/" + filename, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
img.EndInit();
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer. The CreateOptions were what helped me solve my problem. Sadly it is not the answer to this question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the format of the Uri? Maybe try pack Uri? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx